# FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have looked at a lot of these questions already and have tried clear cache, composer update. None have worked. I get this error and I cannot figure it out.

here is my log:

```
 [2016-09-17 04:08:29] local.ERROR:     Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found in /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
Stack trace:
 #0 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(114): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider('Laravel\\Sociali...')

#1 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(60): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest(Array)

#2 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(540): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load(Array)

#3 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#4 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#5 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(253): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home4/office/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home4/office/public_html/public/index.php(53):     Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 {main}
```

Any help would be nice as I don't know if I'm missing something but I followed the install procedure from the git.

Comment: The install procedure from git for what?  Laravel?  Clearly it's saying the ServiceProvider you have enabled in your config, likely config/app.php, 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' does not exist.  So what's your question?

Comment: How do I enable the class..I followed the procedure from Socialite Git. I don't know why it's not finding the class. The class is in the vendor folder.

Comment: `composer require laravel/socialite`?

Comment: Yes that the way I installed it.

Comment: did you define the service provider in your app.php ?

Comment: I add the Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

and

'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class, in the config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

if anybody else has this problem it came down to the composer itself. I had to uninstall and reinstall the composer. I'm guessing the composer was not installing and/or autoloading the files right.